# How do I deploy existing application to new EC2 server?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a python django app and its currently deployed in a instance. I followed this steps: Deploying a [Django Application to Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html)
However due to some specific needs I need to move from t2.micro to t2.small. I followed these steps [Resizing Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html#resize-ebs-backed-instance) but unable to resize my existing one. Whenever I stop my instance AWS creates a new micro instance and my stopped instance is automatically terminated(though my default shut down is set as "stop"). However now I created a new t2.small instance and I sshed into it and installed  some dependencies (which I was unable to do in t1.micro due to small memory). But when I do eb create my app is automatically deployed to a new t2,micro server, So how do I deployed it to the new t2.small instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize your EC2 instance from Elastic Beanstalk application configuration - and Elastic Beanstalk will resize all EC2 instances for you.

Go to:

*AWS Console -> Elastic Beanstalk (not EC2) -> Select your Application -> Configuration -> Instances -> Change Instance Type -> Save*.

Elastic Beanstalk will upgrade all running instances and redeploy your app.

You can find more info here [Configuring Amazon EC2 Server Instances with Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html)

Comment: I already tried from EC2 console, Can you please give some detailed info

Comment: added more details to my answer